# correct way to get data attribute into scope value

Tags: angularjs

So with regular jquery, I can do:

```
var = variable.data('data-attribute');
```

What would be the correct way to do this with Angular?

Comment: Is this as a result of you creating the attributes in angular template? Or reading some third party html? If it's from your template there are likely more appropriate angular ways to do whatever you need using your scope model

Comment: it is from my template, however the value is generated server side, that I want to pick up.

Comment: I think you need to read some AngularJS tutorials...

Comment: Show more template code. Will most likely need directive but whether that needs to be inserted in angular template or server template depends on structure not shown. Also a good chance you are needlessly mixing server side templating and angular templating

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this, you should even use the jQuery command that you wrote above to read data attribute. Do this inside a controller and you are OK. I used jQuery for readability sake, you should use jQueryLite or even Vanilla Javascript.

In your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.expando = $( "#testId" ).data( "test" ); 
});
```

and in your view:

```
<p id="testId" data-test="this is expando attr">Hello {{name}}, {{expando}}!</p>
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HkxChVvmtWEK6DsToHdz?p=preview) for example.

**This hovewer (maybe) is not the best solution!** More suitable should be the use of a directive. Probably that attribute is something that you read inside a Javascript function to do something with the DOM, and the directives are the angular way to reuse component that alter the DOM.

So, your question can't have a better answer until you don't specify what's the use of that `data-attribute`.

Comment: `should even use jQuery` ...why?.Include jQuery just to read data attributes? Doesn't make any sense if it's not already included

Comment: that is a ridiculous response and isn't what OP asked

Comment: Now this answer is getting worse. jQuery or any other dom manipulation code does not belong in a controller. Goes totally against angular best practices

Comment: Stop and think about it a bit .... `here's my solution /*code*/` then go on to say that it's a bad idea. If it's a bad idea why post it as solution instead of starting with the way it should be done in the first place? Realisticaly you keep providing poor approaches instead of directly answering OP's question

Comment: Why doesn't someone else post the correct approach then?